# tkinter delete method does not work with dots and numbers

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have this piece of code in python:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def validar_ingresos(text):
    return (text.isnumeric() or text == '.')    

class VentanaPrincipal(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title(f'prueba')
        self.config(width=200, height=200)

        self.caja_dbp = ttk.Entry(self, justify=tk.CENTER, width=5, validate='key', validatecommand=(self.register(validar_ingresos), '%S'))
        self.caja_dbp.pack()

        def borrar_datos():
            self.caja_dbp.delete(0, tk.END)

        self.boton_reestablecer = ttk.Button(self, text='RESET', command=borrar_datos)
        self.boton_reestablecer.pack()

ventana_principal = VentanaPrincipal()
ventana_principal.mainloop()
```

When the string in the entry has only numbers the button works fine, but when it has numbers and dots it doesn't work. Is there any other method to make this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever tried to print out `text` inside `validar_ingresos()` for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey !

I have tried to change your validation function, and used another one I have used in another project of mine and it works fine !

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def validar_ingresos(text):
       if (
           all(char in "0123456789.-" for char in text) and  # all characters are valid
           "-" not in text[1:] and # "-" is the first character or not present
           text.count(".") <= 1): # only 0 or 1 periods
               return True
       else:
           return False    

class VentanaPrincipal(tk.Tk):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.title(f'prueba')
       self.config(width=200, height=200)

       self.caja_dbp = ttk.Entry(self, justify=tk.CENTER, width=5, validate='key', validatecommand=(self.register(validar_ingresos), '%S'))
       self.caja_dbp.pack()

       def borrar_datos():
           self.caja_dbp.delete(0, tk.END)

       self.boton_reestablecer = ttk.Button(self, text='RESET', command=borrar_datos)
       self.boton_reestablecer.pack()

ventana_principal = VentanaPrincipal()
ventana_principal.mainloop()
```

Good luck!